# Prevent Water Piping from Freezing (price is everything)

Tags: wire, heat, water

I realise that there are a bunch of specific pre-made solutions for preventing pipe freezing but I think I should be able to do it way cheaper myself (I am assuming that the pre-made stuff has quite a markup).

I was thinking just general infloor heating wire maybe (if it is cheaper, I do not really know the cost of anything, right now), but even that is way more that I really need.

I do not need to heat the water much and I do not think I need "smart" wire that will keep itself at some pre-prescribed temperature (I think I can just experiment with different amounts of power and measure the results until I find something that looks good).

It is somewhat indoors, so it will only be a little below freezing sometimes. And it can be monitored.

It also does not need to be 100% safe, if it is theoretically possible that something could happen to the wire and it blows a fuse or starts shocking people who use it, that is fine (and am not looking for a foolproof government approved setup necessarily) (and I do not think a deadly amount of power will need to be going through the wire anyways).

And if I understand electrical wire properly, all I really need is wire that has a relatively high resistance and has some sort of waterproof coating. With some sort of power adapter to plug into the wall and provide the appropriate entergy. And then I would need to figure out how to get the wire outside of the piping to plug it into a power source and how to heat the valves (but those seems like separate questions, easier to lookup myself).

Note: I am an enthusiastic complete amateur.

Comment: well.. but you might start a fire.

Comment: This is much better suited for the Home Improvement stackexchange site.

Comment: This question looks as if there is an expectation that the wire must be inside the pipe, immersed in water (there are references to waterproof insulation, and "how to get the wire outside of the piping to plug it into a power source"). But in fact, the pipe can simply be heated from the outside.

Comment: Ah Home Improvement does sound more relevant.

As for inside vs outside. The problem would be that a wire outside would need to be wrapped around and around to prevent the pipe from freezing and therefor would be far more expensive to make and then to heat. And really you would want to insulate it and in my case protect it, a big added expense.

Comment: "I do not think a deadly amount of power will need to be going through the wire anyways". True enough. But do you have any faint idea how to prevent a deadly amount of current for going through a person? The questions are quite separate.

Answer (score 1):

Waterproof insulation? How to get the wire outside of the pipe to plug into a power source? You seem to be thinking of heating the water inside the pipe. But in fact, you just have to heat the exterior of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

A current-limited power supply connected to the (metal) pipe sounds like it might be a solution. You only need to keep the pipe slightly above freezing.

Comment: That sounds very interesting.
But the water is being used, drunken from; Do you mean limited enough as to not be noticeable by people? That would be powerful enough to raise the temperature the necessary few degrees?

Comment: While this would work, you're going to need a **LOT** of current (particularly with copper piping), and you'll likely get interesting hot-spots at pipe junctions, which will have higher-resistance, and thus generate more heat.

Comment: Well that might work, as for the junction problem (which might not even be a deal breaker), could I not just connect one side of the pipe to the other with wire (giving it a low resistance route past).

But when you say a LOT, do you mean more than I could easily and efficiently get.

Comment: How long is the run? I was assuming a length of pipe running through an uninsulated area, but others are talking about joints and hot spots and so on, so I might be wrong. You'll end up with only a few volts across the section you'll be heating, so I don't expect you'll run into any health or safety problems, and it's highly likely your pipe is grounded anyway so if the supply were to fail the fuse protecting the supply should open.

Comment: In terms of safety... I was thinking of soldering or clamping the supply lines to the outside of the pipe; there would be no solder or flux contamination; the interior of the pipe would be unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

im assuming you have a situation like mine where if the water pipe is not heated till it gets past 4' in the ground it freezes. it is also not externally accessible so the suggestion of external tapes are a waste of time.

1. you need to think of how thick the cable finished will be compaired to the line running in the house.  to big and it will block the rate of flow.
2. since it is drinking water you are limited in coating materials to something approved by the nfs board. all water lines are 'supposedly safe' and have been tested to not leach platics or other chemicals in to your drinking water. assuming you find a material approved for that use it would probably be similer to the liquid rubber for plier handles.
3. the transition fitting could be made from a cap put on a t.  you drill a hole almost exactly the size of the cable you send down and then thread it through.  use a water tight fitting to secure the wire and or more of the rubber coating assuming it handles the pressure that your water pump/supply max at.
4. the 'smart wire' isnt to keep the watter at a specific temprature per say but to keep the wire under a specific temprature so that it doesnt burn out when the water is nonexistant or to warm. the cheep external tapes say no plastic or drain pipes because they require the thermal mass of the water to keep the wire from burning out.  they have a temp sensor at one end that gets taped to the pipe so it knows when the pipe is warm enuogh to prevent burn out.

that aside if you are trying to keep a water line to the shed warm where you only wash off tools and such that are not used for human consumption whether its cheaper or not i cant say the power supply wouldent need to be to fancy and a small thermal switch where if the resistance is = or above ... it turns the power supply off should be quite easy to make. in floor heating wire is likely just as expensive as its usually made by the same companys as the roof/water pipe heaters.. i believe last i checked it was all around 300$ for 80'  a 14' or so water line heater was around 50 to 100 but cant remember for sure.  a mouse ate the thermal sensor cable on mine last winter so i was looking for a while before i figured the issue.